# Apache POI not getting all rows and columns from a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, selenium, apache-poi, testng

I am creating a test framework using selenium, testNG, and Apache POI. So far I have created a piece of code that will get each row from my spreadsheet and insert it into the test. However, on adding a new row it simply ignores the added row. Any  help is greatly appreciated.

Code for getting inputs:

```
@DataProvider(name="ExcelData")
public Object[][] passData() {
    ExcelDataConfig config = new ExcelDataConfig("C:\\Users\\dindo\\Documents\\tests\\d2c-lv-int-01_DATA.xlsx");

    int rows = config.getRowCount(0);
    int frows = rows-2;
    Object[][] data = new Object[frows][11];
    for(int i=2;i<rows;i++)
    {
        data[i-2][0]=config.getStrData(0, i, 0);
        data[i-2][1]=config.getIntData(0, i, 1);
        data[i-2][2]=config.getIntData(0, i, 2);
        data[i-2][3]=config.getStrData(0, i, 3);
        data[i-2][4]=config.getStrData(0, i, 4);
        data[i-2][5]=config.getStrData(0, i, 5);
        data[i-2][6]=config.getIntData(0, i, 6);
        data[i-2][7]=config.getIntData(0, i, 7);
        data[i-2][8]=config.getIntData(0, i, 8);
        data[i-2][9]=config.getStrData(0, i, 9);
        data[i-2][10]=config.getStrData(0, i, 10);

    }
    return data;
}
```

Code for Excel sheet:

```
public ExcelDataConfig(String excelPath) {

    try {
        File src = new File(excelPath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public String getStrData(int sheetNumber,int row, int col) {
    Details = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
    String strdata = Details.getRow(row).getCell(col).getStringCellValue();

    return strdata;
}

public String getIntData(int sheetNumber,int row, int col) throws NullPointerException{
    Details = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
    double doubledata = Details.getRow(row).getCell(col).getNumericCellValue();
    int intdata = (int) doubledata;
    String strdata = Integer.toString(intdata);
    return strdata;
}

public int getRowCount(int sheetIndex)
{
    int row = wb.getSheetAt(sheetIndex).getLastRowNum();
    return row;
}
```

Also, is it possible to merge getIntData and getStrData into one function which automatically knows if it is a string or integer.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the `merge getIntData and getStrData` bit - see https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=jedcua/Parseux/Parseux-master/src/main/java/com/dragonfruit/Parseux/ExcelIterator.java (extractCellValue)

Comment: I think you will need to provide a code sample of how you add your rows if you want your main question answered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you say the code for adding rows, do you mean where the info from the array  goes afterwards or do you mean how I add the rows to the sheet? If the latter, I add the rows using excel but have deduced that it is not a caching problem as when I update an existing row it changes the info.

Comment: do you rerun `wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)` after you modify the xlsx file?

Comment: After I update the file. I completely rerun the code which includes `wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)` in the second sample line 6.

Answer (score 0):

After some extensive keyboard thrashing I finally worked out the chink. It was simply that as Apache POI gets the first row in an xlsx file as 0, there was 1 to less rows in the array. Stupidly enough I found this out by accidentally saving my sheet with an extra letter in the row below the last.